# Best way to proxy http requests in Twitter badge to avoid IE security warning?

Tags: proxy, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to use a Standard Twitter badge on a site with a members area which switches the user to https automatically. On IE 8 this results in the annoying but true "This page contains both secure and non secure items" warning.

I found other threads on stackoverflow and vague suggestions on other sites that I could have my Twitter badge on https pages without triggering security warnings if I implement a simple proxy on my side to call the Twitter graphics and stuff from the regular http urls on the Twitter server, but via https urls on my secure pages.

There are a lot of proxy solutions out there and I'm having trouble finding info about my situation specifically (found aspx directions but I don't use .net stuff). I just need a very simple solution for a LAMP server to handle this one special case.

Alternatively, anyone know of another way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Security warning occurs when you mix http and https objects. Try to serve that image via https

Comment: Thanks, I understand the warning. The Twitter badge is requesting a .js and a css file from Twitter's server via http (it won't serve them as https). I can try grabbing the .js and the css from the Twitter server and saving them on my server so I can call them vai https (not sure if that will work though). I will try to serve it and see what happens.